# Ошибка при установке pyinstaller через pip

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

При установке pyinstaller'а, выводит эту ошибку:

```
C:\Users\Сергей>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/32/0e0de593f129bf1d1e77eed562496d154ef4460fd5cecfd78612ef39a0cc/PyInstaller-3.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpai5ts0z5:
  Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 48, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      backend = _build_backend()
    File "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 39, in _build_backend
      obj = getattr(obj, path_part)
  AttributeError: module 'setuptools.build_meta' has no attribute '__legacy__'

  ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe c:\users\сергей\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpai5ts0z5" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50clv3ib\pyinstaller
```

Comment: Похоже причина в кириллице в пути, например в имени пользователя. Попробуйте поставить питон в корень, например `C:/python`, думаю пройдет. Но ответ с переустановкой pip, конечно, лучше будет :)

Comment: Alexandr Zarubkin Вы не могли бы подробней рассказать, как вам помог модуль wheel, как его установить и настроить, какая была ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Откати версию PIP до 18.1

```
pip install pip==18.1
```

Пробуй установить pyinstaller еще раз

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Обнови версию PIP до последней

```
python -m pip install ––upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось немного иначе - я поставил питон в `C:\Python37` и вопрос закрылся и с pyinstaller, и с PyQt5.

Исчезло имя юзера из пути (ниже выделено жирным):

> c:\users\​**сергей**​\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py

Теперь путь проще:

> c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py

Answer (score 0):

> python3.8 -m pip install pyinstaller

в python3.8 эту проблему пофиксили. Так что установка указанным выше образом проблем не вызывает.

Comment: это скорее комментарий, чем ответ. Либо сделайте его более развернутым, либо удалите оставив информацию в виде комментария.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла установка пакета `wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог откат pip. Просто откатил и все пошло.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // начните, например, с уточнения, что именно вы подразумеваете под «откатом»: замену на более старую версию? на какую именно? и т.д. и т.п.